# PHP не возвращает заголовки

Tags: php, запрос

Нашел код в интернете как послать заголовки и тогда продолжить выполнение скрипта.

```
function run_http_answer($method_name, $params){
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_start();
    $params['method'] = $method_name;
    echo json_encode($params);
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    ob_end_flush();
    sleep(5);
}
```

Подогнал под свой код, но не работает. Ошибок нет, но ответ приходити через 5 секунд, значит код не завершает работу

Comment: Возможно, перед вашим php стоит какой-нибудь nginx, который буферизует вывод

Comment: @andreymal Как это проверить? Функция выполняется сразу при старте программы